MLE of an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process
I am studying MLE of an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process. The setup is the followng: Consider a one-dimensional Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process process $X=(X_t)$, i.e., $X$ is the unique strong solution of the SDE:
$$dX_t = -\theta X_tdt + \sigma dW_t, \quad X_0=0$$
where $(W_t)$ is a standard Brownian motion and $\theta$ is the parameter of interest (for simplicity, we assume the diffusion parameter $\sigma=1$ is known).
I am asking what is the form of the MLE estimator $\hat{\theta}$ for $\theta$ and whether it is possible to derive its asymptotic normality as $n\to \infty$?
If anyone can point me in the direction of a paper/book where this is shown, it would be much appreciated.

Just for my own understanding, what does IID indicate in "IID data sampled from an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process"?  I thought the process was autocorrelated (and mean reverting - did you intend $-\theta X_t$ in your SDE?) and this correlation was essentially about $\theta$.

What does C[0,T] mean here?

@Mingzhou Liu:  As Henry stated,  you can't observe i.i.d. samples of $X$ because the $X_t$ are not independent under the model you wrote. What you might mean is that you observe one path, ${X_t}$, and you want to obtain the MLE. If that's the case, I would check Stefano Iacus' yuima package if you use R ?

@NN2 C[0,T] means the space of all continuous functions on $t\in [0,T]$.

@Mingzhou Liu: So I think you mean that each trajectory is independent of another trajectory ?, where the trajectory is defined as a full realization of the process.

@markleeds You can think of this in this way, though a "realization" is not a random variable and we cannot say indepdence between them. See my updated question for an example for the setup.

Hi Mingzhou Liu: I see better now with the detailed description setup. This material is not my field so I can't help but thanks for adding the extra details. Oh, if you use R, check out Stefano Iacus "Yuima" package, There may be references in there if nothing else.

It looks like NN2 provided a nice solution. I'll check it out tomorrow. Thanks NN2.

It's easy to deduce the dynamic of the process, and then in every interval $[t_{i-1},t_i]$ for $i = 1,..,N$, we have:
$$\begin{align}
&x_{t_i} = x_{t_{i-1}}e^{\theta\Delta}+\int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_{i}}\sigma e^{-\theta (s-t_i)}dW_s\\
\implies &x_{t_i} - x_{t_{i-1}}e^{\theta\Delta}  \stackrel{\mathcal{D}}{=}\mathcal{N}\left(0, \int_{t_{i-1}}^{t_{i}}\sigma^2e^{-2\theta (s-t_i)}ds\right) = \mathcal{N}\left(0,\frac{e^{2\theta\Delta}-1}{2\theta}\cdot \sigma^2\right)  \stackrel{\mathcal{D}}{=} \sqrt{\frac{e^{2\theta\Delta}-1}{2\theta}}\cdot \sigma\cdot\mathcal{N}(0,1)\\
\implies&\color{red}{\left(x_{t_i} - x_{t_{i-1}}e^{\theta\Delta}  \right)\cdot \sqrt{\frac{2\theta}{e^{2\theta\Delta}-1}}\cdot \frac{1}{\sigma}  \stackrel{\mathcal{D}}{=}\mathcal{N}(0,1)}
\end{align}$$
Remark: if we follow your notation, as $x_t$ is a OU-process, $\theta$ must be negative.
We deduce that the $N$ terms $\left(\left(x_{t_i} - x_{t_{i-1}}e^{\theta\Delta}  \right)\cdot \sqrt{\frac{2\theta}{e^{2\theta\Delta}-1}}\cdot \frac{1}{\sigma}  \right)_{i=1,...,N}$ follows the standard normal distribution and from the markovian property of OU-process, they are all independent to each other.
We recall that the log-likelihood of $N$ i.i.d observations $(y_i)_{i=1,...,N}$ following the standard normal distribution is
$$\mathcal{l} = \ln \mathcal{L}= \ln \left( \sum_{i=1}^N\frac{e^{-y_i^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}  \right)=  -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^N y_i^2+\text{const}$$
Then, the MLE estimator $\hat{\theta}$ can be found as
$$\begin{align}
\hat{\theta} &= \text{argmax}_{\theta\in\mathbb{R}^{-}}l=\text{argmax}_{\theta\in\mathbb{R}^{-}}\left(  -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^N \left(x_{t_i} - x_{t_{i-1}}e^{\theta\Delta}  \right)^2\cdot \frac{2\theta}{e^{2\theta\Delta}-1}\cdot \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \right)\\
&=\text{argmin}_{\theta\in\mathbb{R}^{-}}\left(  \sum_{i=1}^N \left(x_{t_i} - x_{t_{i-1}}e^{\theta\Delta}  \right)^2\cdot \frac{2\theta}{e^{2\theta\Delta}-1}\right)\\
\color{red} {\hat{\theta}} &\color{red}{=\text{argmin}_{\theta\in\mathbb{R}^{-}}  \left( \left(\sum_{i=1}^{N} x_{t_i}^2 - 2e^{\theta\Delta} \sum_{i=1}^{N} x_{t_{i-1}}x_{t_i}+e^{2\theta\Delta}\sum_{i=1}^{N} x_{t_{i-1}}^2 \right)\cdot \frac{2\theta}{e^{2\theta\Delta}-1}\right)} \tag{1}
\end{align}$$

Thanks for the reply. I am mainly interested in the asymptotic normality of the MLE estimator as $n, N\to \infty$. Can we obtain this result based on your formulation?

@MingzhouLiu In practice, it suffices to solve $(1)$ by numerical methods. To get what you want (the assymptotic of the MLE estimator), I think we should apply the perturbation theory to $(1)$. The perturbation theory is not my forte. I suggest you as another question on the MSE site: how to solve $(1)$ assymptotically when $n \to +\infty$.
